# Ruby gem to resize PDFs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have a Shipcloud.io implementation in my Rails app. A successful API call generates a shipping label in PDF format. I then need to convert the given PDF to another size (DIN A5 format, specifically). How can this be done in Rails? I checked out the wicked_pdf gem but it seems that only generates html to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php),
then use ruby system call method.

something like,

```
 system("convert original.pdf -resize "{width}x{height}" resized.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

The rmagick gem is one way to go.  It uses the imagemagick binary in the background and therefore you have to install it before you can use the ruby gem.  I use it everyday for work.

There are also other variants as well.  For example the mini_magick gem boosts better memory management and also supports ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick.

https://rmagick.github.io/

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick

Answer (score 0):

what's the size of the shipping label you're currently getting? For a few carriers you can change the size from within your shipcloud backoffice. The shipping labels are all in standard sizes so be aware that when resizing them you could end up with a label that won't be accepted by the carrier.

Comment: Actually, this is correct! Didn't realize there was such settings in shipcloud. Thank you for saving me some headaches/extra work!